# Failed to execute 'createPattern' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The image argument is a canvas element with a width or height of 0

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to make a loupe for a canvas project and I'm trying to make a pattern that involves copying part of the canvas that contains the image copy to a second, smaller, canvas. I keep running into a error stating:

```
"Failed to execute 'createPattern' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The image argument is 
 a canvas element with a width or height of 0."
```

Here is an example of the code:

HTML:

```
<canvas id="tCanvas" width=240 height=240 style="background-color:aqua;">
</canvas>
<canvas id="canvas1" width=240 height=240 style="background-color:#808080;">
</canvas>
<p></p>
<button id="download"   onclick="magnify();">Zoom</button>
```

JS:

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    var base64 = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 0);
    drawing = new Image();
    drawing.src = base64; // can also be a remote URL e.g. http://
    var canvas1 = document.getElementById("tCanvas");
    var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
    ctx1.drawImage(drawing, 0, 0);
    let w = drawing.naturalWidth
    let h = drawing.naturalHeight
    let size = w / 4 // Size (radius) of magnifying glass
    let magnification = 2
    let r = size / magnification // Radius of part we want to magnify
    
    let px = w / 3.5
    let py = h / 4

     let tileCanvas = document.getElementById("tCanvas")
     tileCanvas.width = 2 * size
     tileCanvas.height = 2 * size
    
      tileCanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(canvas, px - r, py - r, 2 * r, 2 * r, 0, 0, 2 * size, 2 * size)
    
      let pattern = ctx.createPattern(tileCanvas, "repeat")
    
      ctx.fillStyle = pattern
   
     ctx.translate(px - size, py - size)

    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(size, size, size, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
    ctx.fill()
    ctx.strokeStyle = "orangered"
    ctx.lineWidth = 12
    ctx.stroke()
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a rather classic problem caused by the 'asynchronous nature' of image loading. Let's take a look at the error message:

> "Failed to execute 'createPattern' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The
> image argument is   a canvas element with a width or height of 0."

It says that either the height or the width of the object sent to the `createPattern()` method is zero but why should that happen?

Let's step back in your code a little.

The object in question is `tileCanvas` and it's width and height is determined here:

```
 tileCanvas.width = 2 * size
 tileCanvas.height = 2 * size
```

So what's the value of `size`? Stepping back a bit further reveals

```
let size = w / 4
```

and `w` in turn is

```
let w = drawing.naturalWidth
```

which is the crux of the matter. `naturalWidth` is a property of an image object - `drawing` in your case. The problem is that you're calling it right after populating it's `.src` property. At this point in time the image might not have been completely loaded, thus it returns zero.

You must wait for the image to be fully loaded until querying it's properties. This is done by listening to the `onload` event.

Here's an example:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
var base64 = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 0);
drawing = new Image();
drawing.onload = () => {
  var canvas1 = document.getElementById("tCanvas");
  var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
  ctx1.drawImage(drawing, 0, 0);
  let w = drawing.naturalWidth
  let h = drawing.naturalHeight

  let size = w / 4 // Size (radius) of magnifying glass
  let magnification = 2
  let r = size / magnification // Radius of part we want to magnify

  let px = w / 3.5
  let py = h / 4

  let tileCanvas = document.getElementById("tCanvas")
  tileCanvas.width = 2 * size
  tileCanvas.height = 2 * size

  tileCanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(canvas, px - r, py - r, 2 * r, 2 * r, 0, 0, 2 * size, 2 * size)

  let pattern = ctx.createPattern(tileCanvas, "repeat")

  ctx.fillStyle = pattern

  ctx.translate(px - size, py - size)

  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.arc(size, size, size, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
  ctx.fill()
  ctx.strokeStyle = "orangered"
  ctx.lineWidth = 12
  ctx.stroke()
}
drawing.src = base64; // can also be a remote URL e.g. http://
```

```html
<canvas id="tCanvas" width=240 height=240 style="background-color:aqua;">
</canvas>
<canvas id="canvas1" width=240 height=240 style="background-color:#808080;">
</canvas>
<p></p>
<button id="download" onclick="magnify();">Zoom</button>
```

Comment: Sweet thanks for the walkthrough to help me understand the issue, its much appreciated.